# Collapse some fields in drill down

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]I have a below requirement in Drill down report. we have below two values under Lost Customers.

Lost Customers, Number of lost customers, Rate%

Here I need to implement , where I always need to show Number of lost customers and implement drill down in only Rate. I mean, Number of lost customers should show always, but If we click on plus (+)symbol which is in Load Customers, Rate should expand.

Please suggest me How to achieve this in SSRS?

Comment: Are Lost Customer, Number of Lost Customer and Rate fields in your dataset?

Comment: Grouping I have done, but not able to hide any particular value and show others. All three are in my dataset. Lost customer is in 1st column and other 2 Number of lost customer and Rate fields in another column. If I apply drill down both will hide or both will display. But my requirements is I need to show Number of lost customers always and Rate should appear only when we click on + symbol which is in Load customer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tablix placing your fields as follows:

[image]

Select the second row and press `F4` to see the properties window.

[image]

In the properties window look for `Visibility` node and use the following settings:

[image]

`Hidden:` This property will hide the row when your user run the report.
`Initial Toggle:` Indicate the toggle `(+)` default state, collapsed or expanded.
`Toggle Item:` Indicate the textbox where the toggle `(+)` will be placed. In this case `LC` is the name of the cell that holds Lost Customer field.

This is the final result.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, Thanks for your time. But here Number of lost customer and Rate are the two values under column Subgroup and Lost customer under column Group. In our design pane only Group and subgroup shows not values. Now how to show one value of Subgroup always and 1 value only when we click on + symbol.

Comment: @ramu, edit your question to include an image of your current tablix.

Comment: @alejandaro ... Hi I have added image. Here group column has value Load Customer and  Subgroup column has Number of lost customer and Rate values. Now If we apply drill down toggle by group, both values will collapse and expand simultaneously. But I want to show 1 value always and another value If we click on + symbol... Thanks